# Plotting a polygon in R from shapefile data retrived from MYSQL

Tags: mysql, r, shapefile, esri, ogr

I am attempting to plot a polygon in R using MySQL as a db source. These data are polygon points that were originally generated from loading ESRI shapefile data into MySQL using ogr2ogr.

(QGIS > OGR > MySQL > R)

The connection to the MySQL server works nicely using RMySQL. The data is retrieved  using an SQL query as follows.

```
shape <- dbGetQuery(mydb, 'select astext(shape) from world where ogr_fid = 1')
```

The data looks like this when output in R.

```
POLYGON((149.751386816 -34.700984991,149.752416704 -34.6955999555,149.755517664 -34.695999944..... ))
```

Can anyone tell me what format is this data in and is there an R library that can plot the polygon?

Many thanks

Comment: Use rgeos::readWKT(shape$shape) - but we can't see your wkt column name so that is a guess.

Comment: Yep, that's the format. Converted to SpatialPolygon and plotted now.

Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use `rgeos::readWKT(shape$shape)` - but we can't see your wkt column name so that is a guess.

You can get a full object with

```
d = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(p, shape)
```

where p is output of the rgeos function.

Probably set `match.ID` to FALSE, and pass in the crs manually with `proj4string` argument.
WKT strings don't store the projection, sad to say.